# Specifying DateTime objects and converting to Unix format using C#

Tags: c#, api, datetime

I'm writing an application and having trouble figuring out a function to dynamically set a range of specific DateTime objects via a "start" and "end" date using C#.

Here is my criteria:

- Case 1: Start at Sunday 12AM and End Sunday 12AM.
- Case 2: Start at Monday 12AM and End Wednesday 12AM.
- Case 3: Start at Monday 12AM and End Friday 12AM.

Essentially, the goal is to have these dates automatically updated each week so that they can be converted to Unix format for an API call. I can't hard code these values because these objects have to change dynamically on a weekly basis.

For example, lets say for case 3 the start date is 4/3/23 with an end date of 4/7/23. Next week when this app fires, I need these objects to update to a start date of 4/10/23 to an end date of 4/14/23.

I am fairly new to development so any examples or guidance would be highly appreciated, even if the solution doesn't specify the exact cases above.

I got this far until I realized that this process cant be a static, hard coded value. Ill use the example based on case 3:

```
DateTime day1 = new DateTime(2023, 4, 3, 0, 00, 00);
DateTime day2 = new DateTime(2023, 4, 7, 0, 00, 00);

long unixDay1 = ((DateTimeOffset)day1).ToUnixTimeSeconds();
long unixDay2 = ((DateTimeOffset)day2).ToUnixTimeSeconds(); 

//URL used for API call
var punchHistoryURL = 

$"https://www.paycomonline.net/v4/rest/index.php/api/v1/employee/{fields.EECODE_View}/" + "punchhistory" + $"?startdate={unixDay1}&enddate={unixDay2}";
```

I need guidance on how to do this, but so that the day1 and day2 objects reflect the current dates next week.

Comment: You might investigate using the Windows Task Scheduler and incorporate it's ability to run at specified intervals.

Comment: Start from DateTime.Now.Date (or UtcNow) and keep incrementing it in a loop with AddDays(1) until you are happy about the DateTime.DayOfWeek.  That's the start date, just AddDays to get the end date.

Answer (score -1):

If you create your app to look at the current date/time you can use the Windows Task Scheduler to run it at the intervals you want:

[image]

Then in your app you can just add 5 days to today's date or calculate how many days, etc.

You can also run it on other than a regular schedule:

[image]

You can also give it a varying "Start In" value where you could, for example, read an Ini file for parameters and other values.

[image]

This will make your application much more flexible and take away the need for a lot of date and other calculations and variables.

An added insider's tip if you decide to use this. Keep an eye on this setting to handle daylight savings time.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Since you're dealing with "day of week", I think you may just grab Unix timestamp and divide `7 * 86400`.

Each day has `86400` seconds and each week has `7` days.
So, a whole week would be `7 * 86400` seconds.

This works by simple math calculation because **there's no leap year stuff involved.**

Because Jan 1, 1970 is Thursday, you can easily get Unix timestamp of 12:00 a.m. of last Thursday.

```cs
long lastGmtThursdayMidnight = DatetimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeSeconds() / 86400 / 7 * 86400 * 7;
```

After this, you may adjust the results by adding or substracting `n * 86400` and `n * 3600` according to your need.

There's a couple of details that you need to pay attention to.

- In some countries or regions, Sunday is the start of a week, while others treats Monday as first day of week. I don't know whether you need timestamp of this week or you need timestamp of future week. But you need to pay attention if you're dealing with multiple timezones.
- You need to deal with timezone issue if you want midnight timestamp other than GMT timezone. My sample code will get you timestamp of midnight of GMT timezone. For example, I live in timezone UTC+08:00. "2023-04-09 00:00:00 GMT" is "2023-04-09 08:00:00 UTC+08:00". So I always need to minus `8 * 3600` to get timestamp of midnight of my timezone.
- If your timezone involves daylight saving time, you need to handle that, too.

Comment: This may be what I'm looking for, I'm avoiding Windows Task Scheduler because I replaced that by integrating with Hangfire (a job server) to fire on a CHRON schedule that I specify. My issue is the time conversion within the application itself, not when it fires externally. I understand your math equations and that makes sense to me, but how would I adjust that formula to grab that exact time (midnight) of the past 3 and 8 days?